# What should I do when I by mistake post a duplicate question?

Tags: support

I some time ago posted a question twice (I was new and never experienced this kind of website)
I did so because I wanted desired attention to that question
but as I experienced this website I think that posting duplicate questions is bad
my question is that

what should I do with that duplicate post ?

I think I should delete that post.
Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the duplicate you're thinking of is [Water rocket physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7340/water-rocket-physics).

Speaking as a non-moderator I don't think duplicate questions are necessarily a problem because often apparent duplicates are highlighting different aspects of the problem. In your case your new question is focussing on the nozzle design while the duplicate is more general.

I have sometimes answered questions I knew to be duplicates because I wanted to write about a particular aspect of the question and the older duplicate was different enough that my answer would have seemed a bit off topic there. For example [Why does the refractive index depend on wavelength?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/why-does-the-refractive-index-depend-on-wavelength) is a duplicate of [Why do prisms work (why is refraction frequency dependent)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65812/why-do-prisms-work-why-is-refraction-frequency-dependent), but I answered the former because I could pick up on some of the points mentioned by the OP and I felt my answer would be better there than on the duplicate. My answer got upvoted a few times so I guess others agree with me.

To return to your question, actually I think it's more engineering than physics and I'd be surprised if anyone can answer it without going off and doing the experiments. If anyone does know the answer I bet it's because they have already gone off and done the experiments. Still, I wouldn't rush to delete the question - wait and see what the site members think. If the question gets closed and attracts a lot of downvotes you might want to delete it because that cancels out the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, delete it.

If you want to get attention to older questions, place a bounty on them.